Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1 Patch 2 overconsumes
Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1 Patch 2 consumes too much energy on MacBook Air M1, 2020. Random access memory - 16 gigabytes.
Operating system - Mac OS Sonoma 14.6.1.
Is there any way to optimise it when running on battery power?
I tried power save mode.

What do you mean by "too much" - when running/compiling or when in idle mode? Normally Gradle requires a lot of CPU, especially if  new gradle version is downloaded and unpacked and of course when compiling for first time. Subsequent runs are usually faster but that can depend on your gradle config and the plugins that are used in it.

when running/compiling
